# Is there a way to emulate syncposition for a grid in code?

Tags: acumatica

I need to perform an action on the currently selected row of a grid.  I can accomplish this by importing the screen into the Customization Project, but this is the only change required for the screen.  With a desire to leave as much of Acumatica untouched unless absolutely necessary (for easier upgradability with new releases,) I am trying to avoid pulling a screen into the customization project only to enable syncposition on the grid.

I have created a graph extension for INSiteMaint to add my action button.  I have attempted creating an INLocation object and then setting it in an Events.RowSelected event handler.  When clicking my action button, the object seems to always be the 1st row of the grid.

```
public class INSiteMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<INSiteMaint>
{
    INLocation location;

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        Base.action.AddMenuAction(myAction);
    }

    protected void _(Events.RowSelected<INLocation> e)
    {
        INLocation row = e.Row;
        if (row?.LocationID != null)
        {
            location = row;
        }
    }


    #region Print Item Label
    public PXAction<INSite> myAction;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Action Label", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXButton]
    protected virtual IEnumerable MyAction(PXAdapter adapter)
    {

        INSite site = Base.site.Current;
        if (location?.LocationID != null)
        {
        ...
```

I also attempted creating a view of INLocation to set Current in an Events.RowSelected event handler.  This does not generate any compile errors, but the screen will not load fully in this approach.  Clearly this is not a safe approach.

```
public class INSiteMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<INSiteMaint>
{
    public PXSelect<INLocation> loc;

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        Base.action.AddMenuAction(myAction);
    }

    protected void _(Events.RowSelected<INLocation> e)
    {
        INLocation row = e.Row;
        if (row?.LocationID != null)
        {
            loc.Current = loc.Search<INLocation.locationID>(row.LocationID);
        }
    }


    #region Print Item Label
    public PXAction<INSite> myAction;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Action Label", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXButton]
    protected virtual IEnumerable MyAction(PXAdapter adapter)
    {

        INSite site = Base.site.Current;
        INLocation location = loc.Current;

        if (location?.LocationID != null)
        {
        ...
```

I suspect my fundamental issue is that without syncposition, there is no callback to trigger my events.  I need to add this functionality to several screens, and this one small change seems like a adding the screen to the customization project is serious overkill for maintainability during upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

I had to initiate callback very similar to what you are trying to do in another project. First, on your grid that you want the position synced, ensure you set SyncPosition="true" set in the px:PXGrid section, and then set AutoCallback to target the IDs of the controls you want to repaint so they update. Here is a snippet from my code:

```
<px:PXGrid ID="gridShipmentLines" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%" SkinID="Details" SyncPosition="true" Height="100%" Style="left: 0px; top: 0px">                
    <AutoCallBack Target="fvLineDetail" Command="Refresh" ActiveBehavior="true">
        <Behavior RepaintControls="None" RepaintControlsIDs="gridShipmentLines,fvShipmentLineDetail,fvInventoryItem" />
    </AutoCallBack>
    <Levels>
        <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="HistoryDocLines">
```

I made a quick button to push as a test action to get the current HistoryDocLine to test getting the updated line:

```
public PXAction<CYHistoryDoc> GetLine;
[PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Get Line", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]        
protected virtual IEnumerable getLine(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    CYHistoryLine HL = HistoryDocLines.Current;            
    return adapter.Get();
}
```

I put a breakpoint on the last line in the function and was able to get the current selected HistoryLine. See if that helps.